# Create file with content if doesn't exist

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix

I'm looking for a way to create a file with specific content if it does not exist.

This command will overwrite the files contents.

```
echo "{}" > test.json
```

I'm looking for a way to write an empty json file without overwriting the contents.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a test for file's existence:

```
[ -f test.json ] || echo "{}" > test.json
```

`[ -f test.json ]` will check if the file exists and is a regular file. If the file does not exists (`||`), `echo "{}" > test.json` will be run.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo '{}' >> test.json
```

Double arrow will append instead of overwriting the file.

Or if you mean to check file non existence before creation

```
if [ ! -f test.json ]; then
  echo "{}" > test.json
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your time here! However, I don't want to append to the file. This isn't what I'm looking for. I want to create the file with `{}` if the file does not exist. That way I can re-run the command. If I run your command over and over again I'll have one file with many `{}`.